# If element contains no elements with certain css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery script to hide an element if it does not contain a certain element:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.main div p").not(":has(span)").css("display","none");
});
</script>

<div class="main">
    <div>
        <p>Hello <span>OK</span></p>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Yo</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This script would hide the `<p>Hi</p>` and the `<p>Yo</p>` text.

How can I check if the divs under `div.main` contain no `<p>` elements containing `<span>`, or another way: if all `<p>` elements under a div are set to `display:none`?... And set those divs to `display:none`.

So the HTML output would be:

```
<div>
    <p>Hello <span>OK</span></p>
    <p style="display:none">Hi</p>
</div>
<div style="display:none">
    <p style="display:none">Yo</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it more simply:

```
$("div.main div p:not(:has(span)), div.main div:not(:has(p>span))").hide();
```

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pdBbU/1/

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to loop through the divs and check if they contain any p elements with spans. Something like the following would work:

```
$("div.main div").each(function(){
  if($(this).find("p:has(span)").length == 0){
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```